# Trying to use a cell value in vba code but need it to be variable and only got it as constant

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to this but enjoying the journey.

I am trying to populate a cell then click a button to run the macro.  Problem is I have the code all working if I include the cells value in the code.....

```
Sub CopyRowBasedOnCellValue()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    A = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    B = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If B = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & A)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For C = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "ASML" Then
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & B + 1)
            B = B + 1
            End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But I want "ASML" not to be constant.  I need it to be variable (ie the value of cell K1)

I am sure it is a simple fix but not very good at this

Bosnia

Comment: `MyVariable = "ASML"` and then you can use it like `If UCASE(Trim(xRg(C).Value)) = UCASE(Trim(MyVariable) Then`

Comment: Hi Siddharth Rout, firstly thank you for your reply.  I do kind of get where you are and I am sure I need to set a MyVariable  but I don't see how this picks up the data imput in K1.  C column is the one being searched  with K1 for K1. Does that make sense?

Comment: E.g. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K1").Value` instead of `"ASML"`.

Comment: If it si going to be always K1 then `MyVariable = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K1").Value`